# HTL Sightly for passing param and specifying a bundle

Tags: sightly, aem-6, htl

Is it possible to pass a variable to the data-sly-use statement using HTL Sightly Use API while also specifying a bundle? 
For example

```
<sly data-sly-use.help="${'com.company.service.Helper' @ myVar='hello!'}"></sly>
```

with the helper

```
package com.company.service;

import com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo;

public class Helper extends WCMUsePojo {

    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
        String myVar = getProperties().get("myVar", String.class);
        // why is myVar is null?
    }
}
```

If it makes a difference, this is in AEM 6.4.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When extending `WCMUsePojo` you need to use the `get` (https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/adobe/cq/sightly/WCMUsePojo.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class) ) method to be able to obtain the obiects passed as expression options.

Also have a look at the *Passing Parameters* section in https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/use-api-java.html